# How to use regex in mutate dplython to add new column

Tags: python, pandas

With familiarity in R and dplyr, I was trying to complete one of my tasks in python using `dplython` and `pandas`.

I am trying to create a new column in the data frame, which evaluates a column using regex and on pattern matching I give value = 1 else 0.

```
import dplython as dp 
import pandas as pd 
import re

a = {'module_name':'eventOutput','module_tpye':'export'}
b = {'module_name':'session','module_tpye':'export'}
df = pd.DataFrame()
master_data = (a,b)
new_df = df.from_dict(master_data)
dp_new_df = dp.DplyFrame(new_df)
dp_new_df = dp_new_df >> dp.mutate(
  to_select=(
    1 
    if bool(re.match(r"(.*)Output(.*)",dp.X.module_name)) 
    else 0
  )
)
```

Getting Error as *`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`*

Expected Output:

```
module_name  module_tpye    to_select
0  eventOutput      export          1
1      session      export          0
```

Thanks From :
Guy with high hopes on python

Comment: print `dp_new_df` before `mutate()`.Comment the last line to see where it breaks.

Comment: I have mentioned the error , it is due to regex . If i remove the regex it works .

Comment: `dp.X.module_name` is correct?

Comment: Yes . It is correct

Comment: You try to match module_name with the string `output(.*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution which doesn't use dplython, which I'm unfamiliar with

```
import pandas as pd
import re

a={'module_name':'eventOutput','module_tpye':'export'}
b={'module_name':'session','module_tpye':'export'}
df = pd.DataFrame()
master_data = (a,b)
new_df = df.from_dict(master_data)
new_df["to_select"] = [bool(re.match(r"(.*)Output(.*)",x)) for x in new_df["module_name"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a package [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) to port `dplyr` and families to python. Now you can do it using (almost) the same syntax as you do it in R:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, mutate, if_else, grepl
>>> df = tibble(
...     module_name=['eventOutput', 'session'], 
...     module_type=['export']
... )
>>> df
   module_name module_type
      <object>    <object>
0  eventOutput      export
1      session      export
>>> 
>>> df >> mutate(
...     to_select=if_else(grepl("Output", f.module_name), 1, 0)
... )
   module_name module_type  to_select
      <object>    <object>    <int64>
0  eventOutput      export          1
1      session      export          0
```